# Date Range search using NEST api for elastic search returning inappropriate results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to use Date Range search in Elastic search using NEST API.

I know that ES stores the timestamp in UTC while doing integration with Nlog.
However, I need to a Date Range search in this @timestamp field.

I wrote these following queries :

From Date Search:

```
qcd.DateRange(r => r
                    .Field(f => f.timestamp)
                    .GreaterThanOrEquals(searchFromDateTime)
                    .TimeZone("+02:00")
                );
```

To Date Search:

```
qcd.DateRange(r => r
                        .Field(f => f.timestamp)
                        .LessThanOrEquals(searchToDateTime)
                        .TimeZone("+02:00")
                    );
```

Here is the rest of the query:

```
searchResponse = (SearchResponse<SearchEventDto>)client.Search<SearchEventDto>(s => s
                    .Index("logstash-*")
                    .Type("logevent")
                    .Query(q => qcd)
                );
```

SearchFromDateTime or SearchToDateTime are c# dates.

Clearly, there is something wrong in the queries, because, it does not take into account the time difference.

For example, since I am CET time, if I give 28.06.2019 14:48 as Search From Date, it should search from 28.06.2019 12:48. Or, the same should happen in Search To date too.

Any idea, how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've prepared a working example for you, maybe you will be able to find an issue with it in your case. If not, update the question with sample document you are expecting to find with your query.

```
class Program
{
    public class Document  
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    } 

    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
        var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
        connectionSettings.DefaultIndex("documents");

        //only for debbuging purpose, don't use in production
        connectionSettings.DisableDirectStreaming();
        connectionSettings.PrettyJson();

        var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

        await client.Indices.DeleteAsync("documents");
        await client.Indices.CreateAsync("documents");

        var response = await client.IndexAsync(
            new Document {Id = 1, Timestamp = new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 10, 0, 0)}, descriptor => descriptor);

        var searchResponse = await client.SearchAsync<Document>(s => s
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    //I'm using date range in filter context as I don't want elasticsearch
                    //to calculate score for each document found,
                    //should be faster and likely it will be cached
                    .Filter(f =>
                        f.DateRange(dt => dt
                            .Field(field => field.Timestamp)
                            .LessThanOrEquals(new DateTime(2010, 01, 01, 11, 0, 0))
                            .TimeZone("+1:00"))))));

        //prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(searchResponse.Documents.Count);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob. I already found the solution (forgot to update here :P ). Thanks again and this is the perfect answer! I have one question though. I see you are using SearchAsync<Document> which searching. Does SearchAsync<Document> improve performance? I know this is not the same question which I have asked above. But, it would be great, if you could help me understand it :)

Comment: Yes, it helps with utilizing thread pool, so when we are waiting for a response from elasticsearch system can decide to use this blocked thread for something else. If you would like to learn more about async/await I recommend to read [Async in C# 5.0](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15816765-async-in-c-5-0) book or check the author's blog(which I can't find at this moment :)).

Comment: Thanks Rob for the answers !

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it should work like that. The following Elastic Query

```
"query": {
    "range": {
        "publication_date": {
            "gte": "2012-05-29T01:00:00",
            "lte": "2012-05-29T01:00:00", 
            "time_zone": "+01:00"
        }
    }
}
```

gives me documents with 2012-05-29T00:00:00 as results.

Just to make sure, are you using the From and To parts at the same time? In that case, I believe the second one would overwrite the first one and should be consolidated into just one query.

What does the serialized query look like if you enable `EnableDebugMode()` in the ConnectionSettings (or manually serialize the query with `client.RequestResponseSerializer.SerializeToString(...);`).
Maybe the c# date is not as expected?